# How to use MSDTC with the same netbios names?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003, distributed-transactions, msdtc

I have a database storage in a windows server 2003 and multiple databases in different windows servers in different cities.
I want to collect data from different servers in to my database storage. 
I have enabled `MSDTC` for `distributed transaction`. I have problem with computer names. most of the  computer names are the same. for example full compter names are: `'his.Albury.com','his.ithgow.com',...`
I know msdtc needs netbios name (`his` name here) but in my situation net bios names are not unique.
what can I do? Is it possible force MSDTC to use Full Computer name or Ip address?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. Here is an extract from a blog post from the Microsoft "Distributed Services Support Team" available here: [Troubleshooting MSDTC issues with the DTCPing tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20151015033358/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2008/11/12/troubleshooting-msdtc-issues-with-the-dtcping-tool.aspx):

> "... you should only put the NETBIOS name of the server with which you
> are trying to run distributed transaction. Any test which is done
> after specifying the IP address of the server or the FQDN of the
> server is an invalid test. You MUST provide the NETBIOS name of the
> server against which you are trying to run distributed transactions as
> **MSDTC uses MSRPC as the underlying mechanism and MSRPC works on
> NETBIOS name resolution only**."